# SSRS pre-printed form second page format issue

Tags: reporting-services

I've not come across anything like I am looking for so either I'm either not asking the right questions (for which I will apologize for re-asking a question) or it's not been asked.

I'm working on a report to print header information onto pre-printed carbon copy forms on a continuous form feed impact printer.  The form is two pages and the header for the second page only contains part of the information that the header on the first page has.

I have the first page header working fine.  I played with using rectangles and it was printing on target on every other page.  The problem comes in when I try to print the page two header.

The way I am formatting the headers is that I have a single cell tablix with a rectangle in the cell.  I've measured out where the 11 fields belong for page one of the form and placed them on the form. This all works correctly.  Below that, I've inserted a second rectangle with the add page break before property checked.  In that rectangle I have two of the fields that are repeated one just above the other (field 1 and field 2).  Field 1 is in exactly the same spot as it is on page one. Field 2 is higher and to the left of where it is positioned on page one.  The report body has no margins.  Positioning is all done directly through the elements themselves.  Field 1 sits about 1/16 to 1/8 inch lower than it does on page 1 even when position top is set to 0 (and there is no page margin). I can position field 2 exactly where I want it to be however.  If I have multiple forms print out, all the page ones are perfect and page 2 field 2 is spot on but page 2 field 1 is always too low.

I tried separating the rectangles but was unable to connect the dataset to the second rectangle.

Is there a better way to do this?  Is there a setting I'm missing that is adding padding to the second rectangle?  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How does it look when rendered to PDF? If PDF has the same issue, you might have more luck searching on troubleshooting PDF layout. If it doesn't have the same issue, then that's your solution!

Comment: I don't trust the web printing tools as the layouts can vary somewhat based on browser.  I always instruct my users to render the report to PDF before printing.  The PDF renderer is the same regardless of the browser or system, making it easily testable and consistent.

Comment: The users are balking at having to do the extra step of rendering to PDF and unfortunately the boss is backing them.  PDF is giving me the same results however.

Comment: Can you post some screen shots?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite the answer that I was looking for but it nearly fixed the problem.  It turns out that the field itself had padding on it.  I'm not sure how as I copied and pasted it from the first page but it moved it up to a acceptable position.  It is still a bit low but close enough that the requester is happy with it.